# PHP preg_match $offset option confusion

Tags: php, preg-match

in php.net preg_match page, it says

> Note:
>   Using offset is not equivalent to passing substr($subject, $offset) to >preg_match() in place of the subject string, because pattern can contain >assertions such as ^, $ or (?<=x).

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Does this mean the **offset** option will be ignored if there are assertions in the pattern.
How exactly assertions affect subject strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the offset isn't ignored, but those assertions apply to the whole string, not the string starting from the offset. So you can get a different result depending on whether you pass a substring or use the offset argument. In particular, `^` matches the beginning of the string, not the offset position.

The example below the quoted line makes this clear:

```
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
```

This doesn't find a match because even though `def` is at offset 3 in the string, it's not at the beginning of the string.

If the offset were simply ignored, you could use a pattern like `/^abc/` and it would match. But this won't match, either, because `abc` is before the offset.

Comment: then how is this option ever useful if assertions like this can make it fail to match anything

Comment: It's useful for other regular expressions.

Comment: The pattern would match though if doing `;
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`

Comment: @l'L'l That's exactly the point that the documentation is making -- using `offset` is not the same as passing a substring.

Comment: Yep, `substr` is the only way to use the assertions in the offset midway like that.

Comment: @Barmar how does php define beginning of string ?

Comment: The beginning of the string is before the first character in the string. What else could it mean? Note that the meaning of `^` and `$` is affected by the `m` regexp modifier; if you use that modifier, it means the beginning of the string or immediately after a newline.

Comment: the beginning of the string is character[logical] before first character. lol